# Excel - apply function to range of cells in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column `A` with dates which has 1000 entries. I want `Bi = Weekday(Ai)` for all `i <= 1000`. How can I apply the method to only 1000 cells in column B and not more(without dragging)?

Comment: would you want to use c# or formula in excel?

Comment: Did you find anything posted useful? Please post feedback, vote and/or accept according to what you found.

Answer (score 1):

With some dates in column **A**; this places the formulas in column **B**:

```
Sub CreateFormula()
   Range("B1:B1000").Formula = "=WEEKDAY(A1)"
End Sub
```

and the formula automatically adjust for each cell,*(just like drag-down)*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need for VBA (though you may want it).

1. Enter your formula in B1.
2. Copy the formula.
3. Goto cell B1000 (shortcut Ctrl+G may work, depending on your keyboard setting).
4. Select B1:B1000 with Shift+Ctrl+Up.
5. Paste.

Answer (score -1):

Copy formula. `Bi = Weekday(Ai)` the count `i` will be updated automatic.